# polyml CommandLine.arguments() returns nonsense

Tags: polyml

I want to read some command line arguments from a compiled polyml program.

However, if I have a program like this:

`print_args.ml`

```ml
val args = CommandLine.arguments()

fun main () = app (fn s => (print s ; print "\n\n")) args
```

(which should just print its arguments and exit)

and I compile it with:

```bash
polyc print_args.ml -o print_args
```

and then run it like so:

```bash
./print_args foo bar
```

instead of seeing foo and bar in the output, I see the following:

```
-q

--error-exit

print_args.ml

/var/folders/kp/kh1w53hx6wbcbbbp5t1mr0hw0000gn/T//polyobj.5349.o
```

I suspect it is evaluating `ComandLine.arguments()` during compile time rather than at run time, and those arguments are some internal compiler things? But I don't know how to fix that. If that is the case, then `CommandLine.arguments()` appears to be rather useless. How do I get the *runtime* arguments in a polyml program? (Note, I have seen solutions for programs that are not compiled with polyc, but specifically want a *compiled* program)

Answer (score 0):

defining the args val inside of main forces the evaluation to be defered until run time

```ml
fun main () = let 
        val args = CommandLine.arguments()
    in  
        app (fn s => (print s ; print "\n\n")) args
    end
```